# Cannot get Bootstrap.min.js to function correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, twitter-bootstrap

I'm at my wits end right now trying to get bootstrap.min.js to work.  I have bootstrap.min.js hosted on my server in bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/

In my header I have

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Rochester Michigan Computer Repair and Web Design">

<title>Tony Weed - Michigan IT Services</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

I'm trying to call a tooltip using

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

but I just cannot get it to work.  I've been staring at this for the past few hours and I'm thinking it's something that I'm overlooking.  I'm hoping a second set of eyes will help.

Would my web host have anything to do with this perhaps?  I'm running through ipage

Comment: See there: http://jsfiddle.net/a4WwQ/68/

Comment: No dice, I've tried adding the script in the header
See:
    <script>
  $('li[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
   animated: 'fade',
   placement: 'bottom',
  });
 </script>

And then calling it with

    <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="This site was created using the Bootstrap API!.">Bootstrap</li>

Comment: Check console/network tab for error

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: I meant check for error in browser's console... BTW `$('li[data-toggle="tooltip"]')` doesn't match any element regarding your posted code. Now you should replicate your issue on jsFiddle if you are still stuck

Comment: It does function in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a4WwQ/68/ 

this is also what I have in my code, the console isn't showing any errors

Comment: Maybe your selector used is wrong. But again, we cannot devine code you are using. Now post all your relevant code in question and btw, using this code, try to replicate issue on jsFiddle

Comment: http://tonyweed.com  You can dig through it as you like.  I am trying to get the tooltip to show on the list item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling initialization of plugin before any of these targeted elements is available in the DOM. You could just wrap it inside document ready handler:

```
$(function () {
    $('li[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        animated: 'fade',
        placement: 'bottom',
    });
});
```

You should really have provided more context in your question, this would have been fixed in few seconds...

Comment: You are welcome, glad you have fixed it. Now accept this answer to mark your question as resolved

Answer (score 4):

From the bootstrap tooltip docs:

*For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.*

You will need to call:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Also you should initiate the tooltip after the DOM is loaded.

Wrap your JS code in [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I've tried this as well.  I've actually tried a number of components from the Bootstrap JS site but nothing has worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will fix the problem but the script should be at the bottom of the page instead of in the the `<head>`